# Failure code -32 MediaPlayer (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, media-player, android-4.4-kitkat

Hello guys my app returns failure code -32 when trying to play a video in Android 4.4 (KitKat).

I can't actually find any information about this errorcode perhaps any of you knows more about this issue?

```
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482): java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -32
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:664)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1692)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.scanInternalSubtitleTracks(MediaPlayer.java:1851)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.access$600(MediaPlayer.java:529)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2198)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-04 13:43:08.966: E/AndroidRuntime(26482):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
I was using IMAVideoPlayer (for commercials). Just had to update the sdk.jar. Everything works fine on KitKat now.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you tell be what was the version you used?

Comment: See my answer here that might be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590046/native-media-player-invoke-error/23312327#23312327

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and this helps me https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/dTkE2BmH1mw.
Here the example of how i did it in my project(this is simple loop over playlist):

```
     videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.start();
     videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.setDisplay(null);
         mp.reset();
         mp.setDisplay(videoView.getHolder());

         PlaylistItem next = playlistAdapter.getNext(lastVideo.id);
         if (next != null && lastVideo.URL != null) {
         lastVideo = next;
         videoView.setVideoURI(next.getLocalFileURI());
         videoView.requestFocus();
         videoView.start();
       }
     });
```

the following lines

```
     mp.setDisplay(null);
     mp.reset();
     mp.setDisplay(videoView.getHolder());
```

do the trick.