# Native Media Player Invoke error

Tags: android

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -32
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:664)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1692)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.scanInternalSubtitleTracks(MediaPlayer.java:1851)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.access$600(MediaPlayer.java:529)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2198)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Can anyone give me idea that in my video player activity App is crashing frequently only on 4.4.2 android OS and logs are here, any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well, using a regular VideoView. I tried just about everything, but it happened randomly when loading new media into the VideoView. Even tried resetting the MediaPlayer instance, as suggest at other places (even though you don't have direct access to that when using VideoView, but you can get a reference to it in the onCompletionListener callback).

My solution was to recreate the VideoView for every new media loaded - if using MediaPlayer directy then you would probably need to recreate it each time you load new content into it.

Since I started recreating the VideoView for each media content source, I have not seen the error again.

Comment: @Mahesh Did you solved the issue.I have the same problem.